# Possible to conditionally $.map items in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible, to add a condition to the $.map in jquery?

My code is:

```
var extrasToSave = $.map(self.extras(), function (extra) {
                return {
                    Descr: extra.description,
                    Pr: extra.price,
                    Cnt: extra.count()
                };
            });
```

I only want to map the object, if `extra.count()` is a number more than 0.  So pseudo code:

```
var extrasToSave = $.map(self.extras(), function (extra) {
           if (extra.count()>0)
             {
                return {
                    Descr: extra.description,
                    Pr: extra.price,
                    Cnt: extra.count()
                };
              }
            });
```

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: this should work fine

Comment: this should work, provided that `self.extras()` returns an iterable object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but you'll still need to return something from your callback function. You can return `null` or `undefined` to remove the item from the resulting array. So something like this should work:

```
var extrasToSave = $.map( self.extras(), function ( extra ) {
  if ( extra.count() > 0 ) {
    return { 
      Descr: extra.description,
      Pr: extra.price,
      Cnt: extra.count()
    };
  } else { return undefined; }
});
```

[Checkout the possible return values for the `$.map` callback in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

> The function can return:
>
> - the translated value, which will be mapped to the resulting array
> - `null` or `undefined`, to remove the item
> - an array of values, which will be flattened into the full array

Comment: Thank you - I'll mark as the answer shortly, when SO allows.  Cheers, Mark

Comment: you don't need to `return undefined` explicitly, not returning anything is the same thing.

Comment: @dav - I always prefer to be explicit with my code. Returning `null` or `undefined` is specifically mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: it is mentioned becuase functions DO return undefined when you don't return anything

Comment: sorry but this answer is plainly wrong, the sentence "Yes, this is possible, but you'll still need to return something from your callback function" is not true.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even have to use jQuery's map function if you don't want to. From the looks of your code you're just mapping an array of objects, so use can use the native JS [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) functions.

```
var extrasToSave = arr
  .filter(function (el) { return el.count()  > 0; })
  .map(function (el) {
     return {
        Descr: el.description,
        Pr: el.price,
        Cnt: el.count()
    }
  });
```

Comment: ooo.. I like this solution! +1! Add a few links for reference to the documentation for the functions you've used and you have yourself a great answer! :)

Comment: native JS map and filter aren't supported by IE<9, that's the whole point of using jQuery, which polyfills them